# Glitched shadows after update 1.5

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

Ever since I updated Skyrim to the 1.5 version the shadows are all glitched. The position of the shadows changes greatly when I move the camera with the cursor or by walking. It's annoying and it didn't help setting shadow graphics to ultra. How do I proceed to fix this? Mods are also welcome in case nothing else helps.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @galacticninja Sure, here you go.

Comment: Do you use ENB or any other visual mods?

Comment: @Thrillho I got "Green Water Fix", "No More Gildergreen Loading" (ENB) and "Shadow Striping Fix".

Comment: @Renan The [answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64571/4797) mentioned that removing the Shadow Striping Fix mod will fix this. That worked in removing the glitched shadows for me. This was probably due to that mod conflicting with [Patch 1.5](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.5)'s shadow changes. I have an AMD GPU.

Comment: @desaivv Do you have the Shadow Striping Fix mod too (same as Renan)? If yes, try removing it ([as suggested by this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64571/4797)).

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it, assuming you're using steam:

1. Right click on Skyrim in your library
2. Click Properties
3. Click Local Files
4. Click Verify Integrity of Game Cache

Comment: It didn't work. I remember using this to fix constant game crashes though.

Comment: @desaivv Everything else seems to be working fine. It bothers me how fast the shadows changes positions though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mod i found very helpful.
The shadows looked much better with this mod on then in the original version.

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/148

Comment: The shadow quality is alright. The problem is it's moving as fast as my cursor movements, pretty much following it which is stupid and annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the [Shadow Striping Fix](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=8043) mod, that's what's causing it. I had the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this! This worked in fixing the glitched shadows for me. This was probably due to it conflicting with [Patch 1.5](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.5)'s shadow changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ATI graphics card? A recent update of the driver, for some reason, is faulty for Skyrim (I had the same issue) 1.5.

The solution is to roll back your driver to a previous version.

(In Windows 7) Go to Control Panel -> Device Manager -> Look for your graphics card -> Right click it and go to Properties -> Click the driver tab -> Click "Roll back driver" -> Accept.

Comment: It's NVidia and Intel HD Graphics. =/

Answer (score 0):

[**This mod**](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=15105) solved part of the problem. The shadows are still following the mouse movements, which means I look to the right and the shadows move to the right. However, it happens in fewer places for some reason.

### [Sharpshooters Extreme Graphics Vision ENB](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=15105)

by [Sharpshooter8](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/modules/members/index.php?id=2963473)

[image]

**Other Features:**

- Highest quality ssao and bloom
- Godrays effect
- Warm interiors with great lighting
- Realistic skin and hair
- Soft shadows which aren't very dark like most enb- check screenshots
- Realistic dark nights with no blue tint
- Dynamic bokeh, almost hexagonal dof
- Vibrant lighting without increasing the brightness too much
- Realistic indirect illumination
- Rich colours
- Water looks Photorealistic
- The sun is Blinding
- Realistic Lighting
- Crossfire compatibility
- Trees have colours similar to Crysis